# Did I get it right?

Tags: discussion

Many questions refer (or will refer) to nuance questions.  Many answers will be given, and much practice will still be needed to understand the nuances and use them correctly.

Therefore, I wonder if there's a way for an asker to be sure that he understood properly the answers by making sentences would be checked by the competent answer people?

Should it be a comment? A question edit? A tag "exercise" along with a reference to the original question? Or is it just no more JLU business, go away dude?

Answer (score 4):

I was going to say, "Just use the comments!" but I see how you might want to post several sentences at one time, and the comments would quickly turn unwieldy.

Can this just be another question? In the question body, you could link to the related question and then ask for corrections on your practice sentences. This way everyone has a chance to answer with their corrections and explanations, no one is confined to the claustrophobic restrictions of comments, and the rep fountain continues to flow happily. Plus, the additional discussion around practice sentences may spin off more questions about related grammar forms.

Comment: There I like the other "question" linked to the original (real) question too. Then, one needs definitely to tag, and/or show in the title that it's not a question per say (since we're not here to do translations…).   And also, how do you rate such a question which is just "ok, so if I got it right, in the two sentences below, I did get the nuance between foo and bar right, didn't I?"?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the comments work really well for this.

Sometimes the comments will show that some questions and/or answers will be improved by editing with the hindsight the comments provided.

One down side is that sometimes too many comments can accumulate and clearing them out requires each participant or somebody with high powers and you don't want to lose a good comment that hasn't been edited into a question or answer.

Comment: One cannot structure a comment, can one? All text will be in a single line. And to whose answer are you going to reply? Commenting the question may mix up with comments related to the question itself. I somehow think that it calls for an extra thread…

Answer (score 1):

In my questions if I have to verify a small portion I use the comments. If it results in asking another question but not enough to warrant creating a whole new question, I would edit my original question and just add on to clarify bigger issues within the scope of the original question(and of course indicating what has been added on).

But this begs the question of what is and what isn't "enough to warrant creating a whole new question".

Just a suggestion but perhaps we can implement collapsible tabs for mini-chatrooms where anybody feels that a portion should be discussed. I'm not sure if it can be done, but it's just an idea. If anybody wants to discuss a certain portion, he can simply insert a "button" or "tab" of sorts into anywhere in the main body of the question/answer. Clicking on it would cause a drop-down tab or something similar. This would allow discussion within the main body, and not clutter up since the tabs will just retract into little icons when not activated.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think there are more appropriate forums for such posts.  For example, [lang-8](http://www.lang-8.com/).

Comment: My understanding of Lang-8 when I had an account there a couple of years ago is that it is more geared toward proper 作文, while this question is more along the lines of creating a list of (disconnected) practice sentences centered on a particular bit of grammar. I suppose it could go either way.

Comment: It's actually used for anything you want.  You just write random things in the language of your choice, and native speakers correct it.

In fact, what I've started doing recently is, I simply write a post where I make up about 10-20 sentences which use the pattern, and post it.  I get tons of corrections all the time.  The advantage of lang-8 is the integrated correction system where people can cross out specific parts of your sentences and replace them, color them, etc.  Plus, it groups corrections by sentence, so you can see many versions of the same sentence side by side.

Comment: BTW, if you're interested I'll post a link to my lang-8 profile so you can see said entries.